Roux without flour or cornstarch
My family and I are gluten free and I’m not in charge of grocery trips. I was wondering if there’s a way to make a curry roux without any flour, corn starch or anything to put into a blender to make a quick flour. Could I use starchy water like if I cooked pasta in a a smaller amount of water to make it more concentrated?

If the concern is gluten, what is the problem with corn starch?  And would not pasta water from wheat-based pasta contain gluten?

Well I don’t have corn starch and I have gluten free pasta

I know the science I was just wondering if there’s any substitute that just isn’t flour because that’s not accessible to me right now
